# Android: Expandable List View Item Buttons Get Pressed When Item Gets Pressed

Tags: java, android

I have an expandable list, with an list item layout that has check box buttons in it. I have state list drawables for the buttons. When the user touches the list item, the buttons transition to pressed state. When the user releases the press, the buttons return to normal state. I'd like the buttons not to transition to this pressed state (it looks weird for the user) The code for the list item looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/vote_minus_one"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/marginBottom"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/vote_plus_one"
        android:background="@drawable/vote_down_button"
        android:button="@null"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

And the button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Pressed -->
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/track_icon_check_green_bg_green" />
<!-- Checked -->
<item android:state_checked="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/track_icon_check_green_bg_green" />
<!-- Disabled -->
<item android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/track_icon_check_gray_bg_gray" />
<!-- Normal -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/track_icon_check_green_bg_gray" />
</selector>
```

Any ideas? It seems like the press on the parent view is getting transmitted to the child views, but I'm not sure how to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding state_focused="true" to the selector for pressed fixed the issue

```
<!-- Pressed -->
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/track_icon_check_green_bg_green" />
```